# Copying without overwriting an entire directory structure in Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, shell

I need to copy only new files from the source directory structure to the target directory structure.

I found that `xcopy` supports the /y switch to always overwrite and /-y to prompt. Is there a switch to not overwrite so I can copy only new files?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xcopy`'s `/D` switch "copies only those files whose source time is newer than the destination time".

Read more about `xcopy` at [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771254.aspx).

Comment: Hmmm, maybe I could try

Answer (score 0):

[FastCopy](http://ipmsg.org/tools/fastcopy.html.en) can do it fast and with a GUI. (it support commandline also).

Comment: I'm not allowed to install any kind of software on the remote machine I'm working :( Thanks anyway

Comment: you don't need to install it, its portable.